# Как в си преобразовать строку, содержащую 16ричное число в инт?

Tags: c

Как в си преобразовать строку, содержащую 16ричное число в инт?

Comment: [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Comment: С обработкой ошибки переполнения или нет? Если да, то @avp и другие советуют неправильно (неполно).

Comment: @0andriy, для анализа ошибок в `strtol()` см. `errno` (в manpage есть пример)

Comment: @avp, *(errno == ERANGE && (val == LONG_MAX || val == LONG_MIN))* ну-ну, успехов ввести `LONG_MAX`, например.

Comment: @0andriy, в чем проблема? `./a.out 7fffffffffffffff 16` это `LONG_MAX`, а `./a.out 8fffffffffffffff 16` уже out of range

Comment: @avp, кажется я понял. Спасибо. Тем не менее поиски в интернете показывают всякие интересные краевые случаи, в которых поведение разное на разных ОС, то есть решение не совсем переносимое...